# How to fetch next and previous item of the current one with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a blog. On the individual post page I want to display a link to the previous, and if there is one, next post published in the bottom. The link should be the title of the specific post.

How do I do that the simplest way with Mongoose?

My current controller looks like this:

```
Post.findOne { slug : req.params.slug }, (err, post) ->
  res.render "blog/show.jade", locals: title: "This post", post: post
```

And the schema looks like this:

```
PostSchema = new Schema(
  title:
    type: String
    required: true
    index: true
  preamble: String
  body: String
  slug: String
  createdAt: Date
  updatedAt: Date
)
```

Comment: please provide information about your schema, so we can help you. MongoDB is unstructured and therefor you can't just get the "next one". You'll need some sorting of a field, to detect what was "before" and whats "after"

Comment: Updated with the schema above. Guess you could use the date somehow?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So let suppose you have schema like this:

```
{
 _id,
 text    
}
```

I suppose that _id is mongo ObjectId, so we it contains post date and i can sort on it

Lets consider that i have opened current post with id equal to `ObjectId( "43cc63093475061e3d95369d")` (instead of this i will use `curId`)  and i need to know next one and previous. Also lets consider that we need get all posts one by one ordered by created date descending:

Get next post you can like this:

```
db.posts.find({_id: {$gt: curId}}).sort({_id: 1 }).limit(1)
```

Get previous post you can like this:

```
db.posts.find({_id: {$lt: curId}}).sort({_id: -1 }).limit(1)
```

Few things:

1. If you don't use mongodb `ObjectId` above code will not work for you, but you can still use `postDate` instead of id and current post postDate instead of `curId`.
2. Take care about order when getting next/prev posts, to retrieve next post you need sort asc, to retrieve prev post you need sort desc.
3. I am not familiar with mongoose, so above scripts is mongodb shell scripts.

Answer (score 6):

Find previous item:

```
Post.findOne({_id: {$lt: curId}}).sort({_id: -1}).exec(cb)
```

Find next item:

```
Post.findOne({_id: {$gt: curId}}).sort({_id: 1}).exec(cb)
```