# How to get previous and next document in mongoose avoiding to go back to the first?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of documents and given a specific document, I want to get the previous and next inserted ones. What I am doing is:

```
const previous = await Picture.findOne({
    _id: {$lt: picture.id},
}).select('title category').sort({_id: -1});

const next = await Picture.findOne({
    _id: {$lt: picture.id},
}).select('title category').sort({_id: 1});
```

I found this in this discussion
[How to fetch next and previous item of the current one with Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153329/how-to-fetch-next-and-previous-item-of-the-current-one-with-mongoose)
and it works, pretty much.

However there is a problem: assuming I have a collection on 10 documents, if I query by the 10th, **previous** will return the 9th, but **next** will return the first. How can I avoid this behaviour?

Comment: In the `next` it should be: `_id: {$gt: picture.id}`

Comment: AH, you are correct, sorry for the stupid copy and paste.

Comment: So I guess this solves it

Comment: It would be useful if there was a `created_date` field for each document, in such situations. Also see: [How does MongoDB order their docs in one collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018048/how-does-mongodb-order-their-docs-in-one-collection).

Comment: That's very interesting, so using The id is not so reliable. I actually have a created date field on that collection, I'll update the code to use it. Thank you for the hint.